# Change keyboard "Enter" key text in Windows store apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, virtual-keyboard, soft-keyboard

I have a question about renaming soft keyboard keys in **Windows Store Apps (C#)**.

Is it possible to **rename soft keyboard key**?

For example, I need to rename key "*Enter*" to "*Send*". Is it possible?

Comment: how about writing a  usercontrol "MyKeyboard"?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to rename a soft keyboard key.  Here is [further information on the touch keyboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465404.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which details how it is a system component (so changing it from an app isn't possible).